# How can I query my queried table so that it only returns the most recent

Tags: mysql, join

In MySQL I made query that joins 3 tables (the film table, inventory table, and rental table) to get the results below:

```
film_id | title    | inventory_id | store_id | rental_ date | return_date
1       | Dinosaur | 1            | 1        | 2018-08-01   | 2018-08-7
1       | Dinosaur | 1            | 1        | 2018-09-01   | 2018-09-12
1       | Dinosaur | 1            | 1        | 2019-10-12   | 2018-10-17
1       | Dinosaur | 2            | 1        | 2019-10-01   | 2018-10-18
1       | Dinosaur | 2            | 1        | 2018-12-01   | 2018-12-7
1       | Dinosaur | 3            | 1        | 2019-02-01   | 2018-02-16
```

How can I query my queried table so that it only returns the most recent return_date for each inventory_id so I don't have unnecessary data (previous dates the same film was checked in and out)?

Comment: Please show us sample data from the 3 tables so we can provide the relevant query.

Comment: Are you using [mysql Sakila sample database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-structure.html)?

Answer (score 0):

From the results of your current query, it looks quite clear that you are using [MySQL Sakila sample database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-structure-tables.html).

I think that you current query is:

```
select
    f.film_id,
    f.title,
    i.inventory_id,
    i.store_id,
    r.rental_date,
    r.return_date
from film f
inner join inventory i 
    on i.film_id = f.film_id
inner join rental r 
    on r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
```

To filter on the most recent `return_date` of each `inventory_id`, you can use a correlated subquery, as follows:

```
select
    f.film_id,
    f.title,
    i.inventory_id,
    i.store_id,
    r.rental_date,
    r.return_date
from film f
inner join inventory i 
    on i.film_id = f.film_id
inner join rental r 
    on  r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
    and r.return_date = (
        select max(r1.return_date)
        from rental r1 
        where on r1.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
    )
```